# How do I join with a column I modified in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to join a table with zip codes and population sizes with a table of demographic information for clients. The issue is that the zip code column in the demographic table is not formatted in a number so I had to reformat it. It was originally formatted as 1111-_ and I reformatted it to be 1111. My issue is that I can't figure out how to refer to the modified column in the join statement.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
R.County, R.Name, Z.[Total Population]
FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
LEFT JOIN ZipCensus AS Z
ON R.Zip=Z.Zip; --R.Zip is not recognized
```

The R.Zip is not recognized because the column was 'created' in the SELECT statement. I could really use any help as I am relatively new to SQL and have scoured the internet for answers without luck.

Comment: R.Zip does not exist... R.PostalCode does.

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously slow and when stuck into a column like this it is almost certainly going to be slow. Replacing that with an inline table valued function would probably be pretty simple. It would be more performant and more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (just for fun) is to use a CROSS APPLY to get the derived value ZIP

One should note: Scalar-Valued Functions can be a performance drain

```
SELECT R.ID
     , R.program
     , R.Status
     , R.Street
     , R.City
     , C.Zip
     , R.County
     , R.Name
     , Z.[Total Population]
FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
Cross Apply ( values ( dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) )  ) C(Zip)
LEFT JOIN ZipCensus AS Z
ON C.Zip=Z.Zip;
```

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't know about CROSS APPLY!

Comment: @mkelley very powerful and well worth your time getting comfortable with them.

Comment: @mkelley I'd be curious which performs better Josh's or mine  :)

Comment: Oddly enough, `CROSS APPLY( VALUES` tends to be inlined into the outer code, and therefore you end up with two references anyway, so either SQL Server will only call the function once, or it will do it twice, but it will be the same whichever way you write it. `OUTER APPLY` usually does not get inlined though, so will get only a single invocation. That's just what I've seen from testing, YMMV

Comment: @Charlieface The caveat YMMV made me chuckle.   I'll have to do a deep dive with CROSS vs OUTER.   Usually, the only time I use OUTER is to include NULL results.  This could be  fun diversion.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I learned, is to wrap the modification inside a subquery, then query that subquery just like it was a table.

*This is your modification logic*

```
SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
R.County, R.Name
FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
```

*Now define that as a subquery*

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
R.County, R.Name
FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
) AS subquery
```

*Then you can join it using your new zip column, like this:*

```
SELECT subquery.*, Z.[Total Population]
FROM
(
  SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
  dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
  R.County, R.Name
  FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
) AS subquery
LEFT JOIN ZipCensus AS Z
ON subquery.Zip = Z.Zip
```

There is another way, which I learned later in my career, called Common Table Expressions (CTEs). I find these much more readable personally, but everyone is different.

```
WITH subquery AS (
  SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
  dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
  R.County, R.Name
  FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
)
SELECT S.*, Z.[Total Population]
FROM subquery AS S
LEFT JOIN ZipCensus AS Z
ON S.Zip = Z.Zip
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize Z.[Total Population] when it's in the subquery, I keep getting an error message

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry you're correct. I have to remove that from the subquery because it's apparently in the Z table. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

R.zip doesn't exist, so  you need to repeat the call to te function, if you need the value

```
SELECT R.ID, R.program, R.Status, R.Street, R.City, 
dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode) as Zip, 
R.County, R.Name, Z.[Total Population]
FROM RegistrationInfo AS R
LEFT JOIN ZipCensus AS Z
ON dbo.fnGetNumericOnly(R.PostalCode)=Z.Zip;
```

Comment: You don't need to execute the function again. You could join on Zip.WhateverColumnIsReturned = Z.Zip

Comment: the solution with join is a sfast as the recall of the function.

Comment: How could executing a scalar function twice be just as fast?

Comment: sql server caches the result and reuses it like in HAVING

Comment: I haven't used scalar functions in so long. My initial comment would not work anyway because it isn't a table valued function.